# What's the difference of onMembersAdded, onMembersAddedActivity, and onTeamsMembersAdded in BotFramework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

What's the difference of onMembersAdded, onMembersAddedActivity, and onTeamsMembersAdded in BotFramework?

I override these three functions, but only the onMembersAdded can be triggered. What's more, we can not get the user name by member.name in onMembersAdded function, in member object, it only contains id.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please find below differences:

OnMembersAdded and OnTeamsMembersAdded both are invoked when members join the teams conversation.
However OnTeamsMembersAdded is a method of TeamsActivityHandler Class and specific to Microsoft Teams only.

OnTeamsMembersAdded takes object of IList which contains additional details like Email, UserPrincipalName, Surname etc. which are not present in IList object used in OnMembersAdded.

As per latest bot framework SDK, 4.0, we do not have onMembersAddedActivity() method available.
Please refer below docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.teams.teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#methods

Refer the links :
ChannelAccount
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.channelaccount?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

TeamsChannelAccout
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.teams.teamschannelaccount?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

When bot is installed for first time the member object contains only the id and name value is null since we are not adding any members.
After bot is added in teams channel if you add any member you can get the member details in member object.

You can refer code samples from below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp